# How to enable c11 on later versions of gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, c11

I currently use `gcc 4.6.3`. My understanding is that `gcc` by default uses the `gnu89` standard and I would like to enable C11, the latest C standard. I tried:

```
[pauldb@pauldb-laptop test ]$ gcc -std=c11 -o test test.c
cc1: error: unrecognised command line option ‘-std=c11’
```

I replaced `c11` with `gnu11` and I get the same error. What is the correct way to enable the latest C standard for gcc?

(Note: I'm interested in the latest C standard and not the latest C++ one.)

Comment: If you are interested in a working wrapper around gcc that impements many interesting bits of C11 have a look into P99, p99.gforge.inria.fr

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The correct option is `-std=c11`.

However, it is not available in `gcc 4.6`. You need at least `gcc 4.7` to have this option supported. In some older versions like `gcc 4.6`, the option `-std=c1x` was available with experimental (i.e., very limited) support of C11.

Note that the current version of `gcc` is `gcc 8.2`.

Comment: correct answer, but to my experience the `-std=c11` is not working yet, be carefull. There are some pieces of C11 missing in gcc, so it is not (yet) easy to work with C11 and gcc.

Comment: 4.8.1 has just been released http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-announce/2013/msg00004.html with fully support

Comment: @bluszcz That's talking about g++ and C++11, does the same go for gcc and C11?

Answer (score 3):

Just to let you know GCC 4.9.x has far more complete support than older versions. If you really need to use this feature, please switch to anything 4.8+
Here is the support status  -- https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status

Answer (score 3):

gcc 5.2.0 works with command line option ‘-std=c11’

Answer (score 1):

Inside a .spec file :

```
%define gcc_ver %(if [[ $(gcc -dumpversion) > 4.7 ]]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi)
# Do we use c11 ?
%if 0%{?gcc_ver} < 1
  %global std_c11 0
%else
  %global std_c11 1
%endif

# if the configure of the package supports it add :
%if %{std_c11}
  --enable-cxx11 \
%endif
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.