# Why scanf_s does not work anywhere other than visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

When I use visual studio, it says "scanf is unsafe, try using scanf_s". But if I use scanf_s in gcc or other compilers, it doesn't work. Does scanf_s works only on visual studio? If so, why? The visual studio website says "scanf is unsafe". If it is unsafe, then why others still uses it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18836839/6309)

> [`scanf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) is Microsoft-specific. Header is stdio.h but not in GCC.

As [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-scanf-l-wscanf-wscanf-l?view=vs-2019)

> When reading a string with `scanf`, always specify a width for the `%s` format (for example, "`%32s`" instead of "`%s`"); otherwise, improperly formatted input can easily cause a buffer overrun.
>   Alternately, consider using `scanf_s`, `_scanf_s_l`, `wscanf_s`, `_wscanf_s_l` or `fgets`.

See more at "[Why didn't gcc implement `_s` functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50724865/6309)"

[`pmg`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg) adds in the comments that `scanf_s()` is [Standard C11 (optional)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.2).
That means that [activating `c11` with `gcc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256586/how-to-enable-c11-on-later-versions-of-gcc) might be enough.

However [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn) adds:

> IIRC, Microsoft's version doesn't follow the standard.
>   Plus no other major C library vendor has bothered to implement Annex K, so it might as well be MS specific for all intents and purposes.

[`pmg`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg) confirms:

> My `gcc` (version 6.3.0) does not recognize `scanf_s()` with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic ...`

Comment: `scanf_s()` is Standard [C11 (optional)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.2)

Comment: @pmg IIRC, Microsoft's version doesn't follow the standard. Plus no other major C library vendor has bothered to implement Annex K, so it might as well be MS specific for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @pmg So activating c11 with gcc would be enough? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256586/how-to-enable-c11-on-later-versions-of-gcc)

Comment: My gcc (version 6.3.0) does not recognize `scanf_s()` with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic ...`